# Pandas replace not working on known values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

have a quick question about pandas replace.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np


    infile = pd.read_csv('sum_prog.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(infile)
    df_no_na = df.replace({0: np.nan})
    df_no_na = df_no_na.dropna()

   print(df_no_na.head())
   print(df.head())
```

This code will return:

```
   Cell ID  Duration  ...  Overall Angle Median  Overall Euclidean Median
   0   372003       148  ...                   0.0        1.9535615635898635
   1   372005       536  ...     45.16432169606084         37.85959470668756
   2   372006       840  ...                   0.0        1.0821891332154392
   3   372010       840  ...                   0.0        1.4200380286464513
   4   372011       840  ...                   0.0        1.0594536197046835

  [5 rows x 20 columns]
  Cell ID  Duration  ...  Overall Angle Median  Overall Euclidean Median
  0   372003       148  ...                   0.0        1.9535615635898635
  1   372005       536  ...     45.16432169606084         37.85959470668756
  2   372006       840  ...                   0.0        1.0821891332154392
  3   372010       840  ...                   0.0        1.4200380286464513
  4   372011       840  ...                   0.0        1.0594536197046835
```

I have done this exact same thing and it has worked before I have no idea why it won't now, any help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `df.replace()` a set instead of a dictionary. You need to replace `{0, np.nan}` with `{0: np.nan}`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


infile = pd.read_csv('sum_prog.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(infile)
print(df)

df_no_na = df.replace({0: np.nan})   # change this line
print(df_no_na)

df_no_na = df_no_na.dropna()
print(df_no_na())


index   Cell_ID Duration    Overall_Angle_Median    Overall_Euclidean_Median
1   1.0 372005.0    536.0   45.164322   37.859595
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response, you're right I wasn't properly passing the dict, however it still  does not work.....

Comment: @MattKinahan, Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'doesn't work'? What are you running? What do you see as output?

Comment: it just will not replace the 0.0 value with None so will not get dropped. So both dfs look the exact same, also python 3.9

Comment: Can you read in the dataframe again and just run `df.replace({0: np.nan})`, *without the assignment* and see if that shows the values being replaced?

Comment: Nothing.... even did it on a different computer (desktop --> laptop) and still will not replace.... ran 'df.replace({0: np.nan}, inplace=True)'

Comment: If you use `inplace=True`, then `df.replace()` returns `None`.  You won't see anything unless you then `print(df)`. Just run *exactly* `df.replace({0: np.nan})`, and see what it shows.

Comment: yeah thats what I did and it still didn't work, no idea why, I have literally run the exact same piece of code on another df and worked fine

Comment: Okay, can you copy and paste the code from my answer (with some additional `print()`` statements I just added), run that, and copy the output to the end of your answer? Maybe also post a screenshot of it, but as a general rule, screenshots are not great for debugging purposes.